# Positioning subviews for rotation

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I'm looking for the best technique for positioning subviews of a UIView in order to take into account rotation. The positioning of the subviews is based on the frame of the UIView.

My basic scenario is a top-level modal UIViewController whose view contains a bunch of subviews. I'm getting the rotation notification fine, but I'm struggling with what the best design pattern should be so that my subviews are positioned corrected both normally and during rotation.

I was using layoutSubviews for positioning. layoutSubviews is called both normally (during view creation) and during rotation. The problem is that when it's called during rotation, the frame width/height has yet to be flipped. So, it seems that I cannot reliably do subview positioning during this function. This seems like a major flaw in design as this is the exact purpose of this method, right?

When I'm doing now, instead, is positioning subviews in my own function, passing a CGRect frame that I flip during rotation and leave alone (self.frame) during normal subview creation. Is this correct? Better solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into setting the `autoresizingMask` on your subviews, rather than trying to resize all the subview individually? It would be much simpler if you could use that instead.

Comment: I need to reposition the subviews, not just have them resized based on the frame of my view. The autoresizingMask doesn't do repositioning, correct?